# Log in is not working in my project

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, javafx-2

I am developing a project in javafx using NetBeans IDE. I am using MySQL database. Now am working with the log in section of my project. I created an account for a user already. My code is below :

```
public class Login extends BorderPane {     
TextField t1,t2,t4,t5,t11;
PasswordField t3,pw11;
ComboBox comboBox1,comboBox2,comboBox3;
Button b1;

private Connection connect = null;
private Statement statement = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

private Connection connect2 = null;
private Statement statement2 = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = null;
private ResultSet resultSet2 = null;

public Login() {

    setTop(loginHBox1());
    setLeft(loginVBox1());
    setRight(loginVBox2());

    getStylesheets().add
    (Login.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());

}

private HBox loginHBox1() {

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 10, 180));
    hbox.setSpacing(10);

    Label lb1=new Label("LOG IN OR CREATE NEW ACCOUNT");
    lb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.MEDIUM,26));
    lb1.setTextFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);

    hbox.getChildren().addAll(lb1);

    return hbox;
}

private VBox loginVBox1() {

    VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20,30,15,40));
    vbox.setSpacing(10);

    Label lb3=new Label("LOG  IN");
    lb3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    lb3.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.MEDIUM,24));
    lb3.setTextFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);

    Label lb1=new Label("Username");
    lb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.MEDIUM,16));
    lb1.setTextFill(Color.NAVY);

    t11=new TextField();
    t11.setPrefSize(180,30);

    Label lb2=new Label("Password");
    lb2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    lb2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.MEDIUM,16));
    lb2.setTextFill(Color.NAVY);

    pw11=new PasswordField();
    pw11.setPrefSize(180,30);

    b1=new Button("LOG IN");
    b1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
    b1.setPrefSize(100,40);
    b1.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

    b1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        try 
        {
            signin();
        } 
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }
    });

    final Button b5=new Button("BACK");
    b5.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
    b5.setPrefSize(100,40);
    b5.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

    b5.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    ((Stage)b5.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(new Scene(new WelcomePage()));
     }
    });

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(lb3,lb1,t11,lb2,pw11,b1,b5);

    return vbox;
}

public void signin() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect2 = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?"
          + "user=root&password=virus");

       statement2 = connect2.createStatement();

        preparedStatement2 = connect
      .prepareStatement("select username,password from "+t11.getText()+";");
        resultSet2 = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      writeResultSet(resultSet2);

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
              }  
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    close1();
}
   }

private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

while (resultSet.next()) {

  String username = resultSet.getString("username");
  String password = resultSet.getString("password");
  String usr = (String)t11.getText();
  String pwd = (String)pw11.getText();

  if( t11.getText().equals(username) && pwd.equals(password))
  {
    ((Stage)b1.getScene().getWindow()).setScene(new Scene(new UserPage()));
  }
  else
  {
      //...WARNING MESSAGE
  }
}
}

private void close1() {
try {

    if (resultSet2 != null) {
    resultSet2.close();
  }

  if (statement != null) {
    statement.close();
  }

  if (connect != null) {
    connect.close();
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {

}
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This code doesn't contain the import statements and  the account creating section. I excluded both. The account section is working fine. When I enter both username and password and click log in button a lot of exceptions are shown. I will post some of it h:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at login.Login.signin(Login.java:151)
at login.Login$1.handle(Login.java:115)
at login.Login$1.handle(Login.java:110)
```

How can I correct my errors and make the log in successful ?

Comment: When I am trying to map line 151 by copy-pasting your code to eclipse it does not come in signIn() method. Which code snippet is pointing to line 151? Also, please put logger or else debug point to see whether you are able to connect with DB by inspecting Connection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your signin code your are instantiated `connect2` but then using `connect`

```
connect2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?"
          + "user=root&password=virus");

preparedStatement2 = connect.prepareStatement(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was error. Also the prepareStatement object was also misused. I correct it and ran my code. Now  I can log in. But a new Exception is appearing now.